# Caching with Node Cache doesnt persist data

Tags: javascript, caching

I am trying to build a cache using node-cache npm module, where I want to save the first 100 records of the API call in the cache, so I don't have to call the API again. The front end is build with React.

The problem I have is that every time the browser refreshes, I lose the cache. My code looks like this:

```
getAll: () => {
    if (cache.keys().length) {
      console.log(' data persists', )
      const keysArr = cache.keys();
      return getAllCachedRecords(keysArr)
    }
    cache.mset([{key: 1, val: {a: 1, b: 2}}, {key: 2, val: {a: 1, b: 2}}, {key: 3, val: {a: 1, b: 2}}])
    console.log(cache.keys(), 'here i can see the saved data outside if statement')
    return fetchRequest(BASE_URL)
  }

const fetchRequest = (url) => {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.status <= 400 ? res : Promise.reject(res))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res=>{
        setAllCachedRecords(res);
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`${err.message} while fetching /${url}`)
      });
};
```

Basically, I want my function getAll to first check if I have something in the cache(cache.keys returns the array of the existing keys), and if so, return this info. Otherwise, call the API, set the info in the cache, and return that info.

However, the cache.keys().length is never true, even if I manually set a couple of keys outside the conditional statement, and check their existence afterwards. Am I flushing the data when I refresh the browser, and if so, what solutions do I have to not have to call the API every time?

Comment: Can you call getAll() immediately after setting the data in the cache in the same request? This is just to make sure that you're successfully setting the data in the cache.

Comment: I have tried that - setAllCachedRecords is performing these actions:
- setting the data in the cache (cache.mset(...);
- calling getAllCachedRecords
- console logging these retrieved records
and so far everything seems ok. The problem is when I am calling the main getAll() function, which decides whether to use the cache data or call the API - here everytime I seem to start over with an empty cache...

Comment: Can i see where have you declared the variable 'cache'? Probably it is being reset on every HTTP request.

Comment: "*Am I flushing the data when I refresh the browser*" - yes. Reloading the page runs the code from the beginning again in a fresh environment. Use HTTP caching instead.

Comment: Well, until you're http server is running and you have declared the variable before the http server execution, it should not get reset.

Comment: @Niteshmorajkar 

import NodeCache from 'node-cache';
const ttl = 60 * 60 * 1; // cache for 1 Hour
const cache = new NodeCache(ttl); // Create a new cache service instance

Comment: Does your http server code execute after above code?

Comment: I guess not.  To clarify, right now I don't have a backend set up, and the calls made to the API and to the cache are through React's server, which I guess is restarting everytime the browser is refreshed. Therefore, would I need to set up a backend which handles the cache and passes this info to React's server?

Comment: Oh I got it.. Can you save the data in browser's localstorage? This will solve your problem.

Comment: I would also recommend you to remove the nodejs tag as it is misleading.